# Inline minified CSS files between <head> tags rather than HTTP <link> to them

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, performance

I have been following and working with Google Pagespeed Insights checker. I'm so close to 100%; and while I know that all the suggestions listed in the insights check is advice, and nowhere near based on every need, I need to know what is the general consensus of placing minified CSS bundles directly between `<style></style>` tags on each page instead of doing 1x `<link href=...>` file.

To clarify, what I am saying is doing this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
<?php include('/path/to/compiledMinified.css');
</style>
</head>
```

Which outputs to something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 *//*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{font-family:sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background-color:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight.........
</style>
</head>
```

Now the Google Pagespeed Insights score goes from 81 (yellow) all the way up to 96 (green).

The minified CSS in question has all the global CSS styles, fontawesome, bootstrap and a couple of other things all gulped into one minified CSS file.

The downsides of this are obvious, the CSS won't be cached by the browser, and will need to be downloaded on every page of the website between the `<head>` page.
On the other hand, the pages on the site aren't that big anyway, and probably saving the HTTP request in increased performance anyway.

But you never hear of it do you? Sticking bootstrap etc etc inbetween `<style>` tags between the `<head></head>` tags.

What is the 'right way' to do this?

Comment: The downsides are obvious and the tradeoff isn't worth it. It may be occasionally worth it for smaller websites, but even for something like Bootstrap, you're better off keeping it in a separate file.

Comment: Answers go down there, @CalebAnthony. :)

Comment: It's not really an answer to his question, though. He asked the right way to do it, and my comment addressed something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's no right way to do it. You should never be doing inline styles with such big files. I highly recommend you to stick with external file.

If you stick to your idea though - I think there's no better way than just put it in between of